# Retrieving data from JSONObject using NSDictionary

Tags: ios, json, objective-c, xcode

In this way I store my JSONArray using NSUserDefaults:

```
 NSArray* notifications = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:todo.dictionary, nil];
     NSData *jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:notifications options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted error:&writeError];
     NSDictionary *results = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:jsonData options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:nil];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:results forKey:@"todosJson"];
```

After this, if I print my array I get:

```
NSDictionary *myJSON = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"todosJson"];
NSLog(@"JSON Output: %@", value);
```

and:

```
JSON Output: (
        {
        category = "cat";
        dueDate = "";
        name = dasdasdas;
        note = dasdasd;
    }
   {
        category = "cat2";
        dueDate = "ddd";
        name = dasdasdas2;
        note = dasdasd;
    }
)
```

How can I get every category of every JSONObject?
I want to loop over this dictionary and get (in this example) "cat" and "cat2".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming you just want to loop over and extract the 'category' value

You can do something like this

```
for (NSDictionary *dict in values) {
  NSLog(@"Category: %@", dict[@"category"]);
}
```